# ¿Cómo darle un transition a clip-path?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo un div con un clip-path que forma un triangulo, al hacer hover se hace cuadrado, pero no se hace una animación correspondiente con el transition.

```js
$(".brush_about").hover(function () {
        $(this).children("video")[0].play();
        $('.text-container-about').fadeOut(1000);
    }, function () {
        var el = $(this).children("video")[0];
        el.pause();
        $('.text-container-about').fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

```css
.brush_container {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 5px #0003); }
 .brush_container .brush_about {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 34%, 0 9%, 23% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 34%, 0 9%, 23% 100%);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    transition: 0.5s ease; }
    .brush_container .brush_about .vid_ {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%; }
    .brush_container .brush_about:hover {
      -webkit-clip-path: none;
      clip-path: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brush_container">
   <div class="brush_about">
     <video class="vid_" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debe coincidir el número de vértices en el principio y el final de la animación.

Lo primero es definir el tamaño que tendrá el elemento al final, en este caso será el tamaño del vídeo: `320x176` y después en el `:hover` se crea un polígono que permita verlo completo en lugar de usar `clip-path: none`.

Por otra parte, como el polígono inicial también tiene que tener cuatro vértices para poder animarlo, dos de ellos deben estar en la misma posición para crear un triángulo:

```js
$(".brush_about").hover(function() {
  $(this).children("video")[0].play();
  $('.text-container-about').fadeOut(1000);
}, function() {
  var el = $(this).children("video")[0];
  el.pause();
  $('.text-container-about').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
.brush_container {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 5px #0003);
}

.brush_container .brush_about {
  position: relative;
  height: 176px;
  width: 320px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 85% 33%, 85% 33%, 33% 85%);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.brush_container .brush_about .vid_ {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.brush_container .brush_about:hover {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brush_container">
  <div class="brush_about">
    <video class="vid_" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```